# how to filter adobe fileSystemTree

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I was wondering how can i filter the [fileSystemTree](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/FileSystemTree.html) of adobe air.
I will like the fileSystemTree only shows folder that consist of images only.

I tried with the code below, by filtering the folders with extensions of .jpg and .png.
This will display only files that have that extension. Therefore that file does not consist of any images, i will not want to display it when the fileSystemTree is first initialize.

```
<mx:FileSystemTree id="fileSystemTree"
                   includeIn="displayState,displayState2,initialScreen,thumbnailState" x="25"
                   y="25" width="300" height="88%" contentBackgroundColor="#D5D5D5"
                   extensions="{fileExtensions}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own custom logic to show/hide fileSystemTree. Check the dataprovider File object and iterate if the Children folders have the images with the extension. If it doesn't contain it then hide the component other keep visible "true". You can try to extend the FileSystemTree component and check for commitProperties and updateDisplayList methods.

Hope it helps..